# Update aliases through admin or module?

Tags: path-aliases, nodes

I used the blog module for what I am calling "story" on the site I am building.

The URI and various parts of the site still say "BLog" -- most noticeably when the user attempts to add a new blog.

I have figure out I can just override the URI using aliases through admin, but I am wondering if it would make more sense to simply rename the 'blog' references in the table itself, via a module or one time hack?

Opinions?

EDIT | I also want to change the "forum" module to "forums" making all references plural not singular

Answer (score 0):

[Pathauto](https://drupal.org/project/pathauto) module fits in exactly to serve your requirements.

> The Pathauto module automatically generates URL/path aliases for various kinds of content (nodes, taxonomy terms, users) without requiring the user to manually specify the path alias. This allows you to have URL aliases like /category/my-node-title instead of /node/123. The aliases are based upon a "pattern" system that uses tokens which the administrator can change.

Comment: not sure I explained myself correctly...I am using pathauto but the problem is the "forum" module assumes the URI of "forum" and I need to change it to "forums" -- and when it uses "forums" I need it to be "forum"